# Find out the Store name from the given reference table data, available in all the cities

Tags: sql-server

Sample data:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| Id | CityName | StoreName |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Delhi    | A         |
|  2 | Goa      | C         |
|  3 | Delhi    | C         |
|  4 | Pune     | A         |
|  5 | Pune     | B         |
|  6 | Pune     | C         |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----------+-----------+
| CityName | StoreName |
+----------+-----------+
| Delhi    | C         |
| Goa      | C         |
| Pune     | C         |
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: please provide expected result and also share what have you tried

Comment: thanks for the response, I am not able to understand how to start with.. this was asked in the interview.

Comment: please take some time to  got through this link :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Id INT, CityName VARCHAR(50), StoreName CHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'Delhi', 'A' ),         
(2, 'Goa', 'C' ),         
(3, 'Delhi', 'C' ),         
(4, 'Pune', 'A' ),         
(5, 'Pune', 'B' ),         
(6, 'Pune', 'C' );

    SELECT CityName, Max(StoreName) As StoreName
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY CityName;
```

Result:

```
+==========+===========+
| CityName | StoreName |
+==========+===========+
| Delhi    | C         |
+----------+-----------+
| Goa      | C         |
+----------+-----------+
| Pune     | C         |
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; the query will work for the given data but if the data is as follows.

New Data

DECLARE @T TABLE (Id INT, CityName VARCHAR(50), StoreName CHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'Delhi', 'A' ),         
(2, 'Goa', 'B' ), 
(3, 'Delhi','B'),        
(4, 'Delhi', 'C' ),         
(5, 'Pune', 'A' ),         
(6, 'Pune', 'B' ),         
(7, 'Pune', 'C' );


Result 

CityName StoreName
Delhi    C
Goa            B
Pune    C

But the result should be

CityName StoreName
Delhi    B
Goa            B
Pune    B

Comment: @MSBILearner Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, you put a desired outputs and I answer your question, if there is something else please edite your question or ask new one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the comment you left with Sami. But what you can do is this if you want the `storenames` to equal to `b`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Id INT, CityName VARCHAR(50), StoreName CHAR(1) ); INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1, 'Delhi', 'A' ), (2, 'Goa', 'B' ), (3, 'Delhi','B'), (4, 'Delhi', 'C' ), (5, 'Pune', 'A' ), (6, 'Pune', 'B' ), (7, 'Pune', 'C' );

select cityname, storename from @t
where storename = 'b'
group by storename, cityname
```

to answer your original question you can use what Sami did or:

```
select cityname, storename from @t
where storename = 'c'
group by storename, cityname
```

if neither answers your question please post a new question or update your question appropriately with the proper business rules and desired results. But this looks to be sql basics, try looking over the link TheGameiswar left you.